# Derive the exact class from the wrapping class Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Lets assume that we have the following structure:

```
class BaseClass {
    ...
    String typeOfSomeClass;
    SomeClassBasedOnType someClassBasedOnType;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=As.PROPERTY, property="BaseClass.typeOfSomeClass")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = SomeClassBasedOnTypeImpl1.class, name="type1"),
    @Type(value = SomeClassBasedOnTypeImpl2.class, name="type2")
})
interface SomeClassBasedOnType {
}
@JsonTypeName("type1")
class SomeClassBasedOnTypeImpl1 implements SomeClassBasedOnType {
    String str1;
}
@JsonTypeName("type2")
class SomeClassBasedOnTypeImpl2 implements SomeClassBasedOnType {
    String str2;
}
```

With the above structure I want to store a JSON using Jackson. The two possible JSONs that I need to parse are:

```
{"typeOfSomeClass":"type1", "someClassBasedOnType": {"str1":"someValue"}}
```

and

```
{"typeOfSomeClass":"type2", "someClassBasedOnType": {"str2":"someValue"}}
```

Here is my code that I use to deserialize the JSON:

```
BaseClass baseClass = new ObjectMapper().readValue(someJsonAsString, BaseClass.class);
```

The only thing is that I don't know how to get the type from the "base" JSON. The syntax: `...property="BaseClass.typeOfSomeClass"` still looks for a property in the SomeClassBasedOnType implementing class. Any ideas how to specify that I need the property from the wrapping class ?

Just to clarify the "base" JSON contains many keys, which are all the same including the key someClassBasedOnType. The key someClassBasedOnType however may contain two different JSON objects(with different keys) and the way to distinguish those objects is based on the value of the key in the "base" JSON called typeOfSomeClass.

Comment: Related to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657521/derive-the-exact-class-of-the-wrapper-class-gson

Comment: Btw, I have solved the problem using custom Deserializer. However there should be more "elegant" solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for my problem, however the `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` is since 1.9 version :(

[Jackson JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757431/jackson-jsontypeinfo-as-external-property-doesnt-work-as-expected/20914599)